# Aligning Parallel Sentences for Languages without a Written Form

Tags: nlp, machine-translation

what are the old or current approaches for word alignment for parallel text?
what is the best approach of word alignment for under resourced language or language without a written form?

so far i found about the Levenshtein distance algorithm, and a little bit about the IBM models and some others

if there is any suggestions or links that i can refer to that would be helpful

Comment: When you say without a written form, you mean you want to align audio?  The best aligners I currently know of are [Eflomal](https://github.com/robertostling/eflomal) and [SimAlign](https://github.com/cisnlp/simalign).

Answer (score 0):

Without more specifics, it's hard to know what to suggest, but you may want to consider [Facebook's Laser](https://github.com/facebookresearch/LASER) or [Google's BERT](https://github.com/google-research/bert), both have very good sentence embedding models that can be used for alignment tasks.